# Change color in jQuery

Tags: jquery, colors

So far I have this code which helps users know if the password is spelled right, but I want to make the color of the texts green/red for match/do not match.

```
$(function() {

    $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(function() {
        var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(password == $(this).val() ? "Passwords match." : "Passwords do NOT match!");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.css()` to change color of text

```js
$(function() {
$("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(function() {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    if(password == $(this).val()) {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css("color","green"); 
    } else {
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do NOT match!");
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").css("color","red");
    }  
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtNewPassword" />
<input type="text" id="txtConfirmPassword" />
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(function() {
        var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
        if(password == $(this).val())
        {
           $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
           $(this).css('color', 'green');
        }else{
          $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do NOT match!");
          $(this).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Add a description explaining what you did please

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(function() {
        var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(password == $(this).val() ? "Passwords match." : "Passwords do NOT match!").css('color','green');
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set to confirm password

```
  $("elmLocator").css("color","red");
```

But on keyup don't forget to change it back.